# Multiple Foreign keys in single Table Entity Framework 4.3.1

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-express, foreign-key-relationship

I'm new to EF and have read some Tutorials and Googled many days to find a solution for my problem. Sorry my english is not the best but i want try to formulate my Question.

## Data Model

My Model created from SQL Express Database (shrinked Version to better Understand) :

[See Image](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B3YbPDbDZjtFY3hPOGIzLXJRVzJqa1o5U3I1YWdqUQ):

## Create Sample Data

Now i try to fill my DB with Demo Data. I create an Object of Liegenschaft and fill data in this. Simple Version to show my Tree of Data (real Version can have many Object of HAUS in ObjektMenge=List and for ObjektMenge=List too.

```
List<Liegenschaft> LL = new List<Liegenschaft>(); 

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            Liegenschaft L = new Liegenschaft()
            {
                Strasse = "demostreet1",
                HausMenge = new List<Haus>(){ 
                new Haus(){ 
                    Nummer = 21, 
                    ObjektMenge = new List<Objekt>(){
                        new Objekt(){ 
                            Zimmer = 221,
                            MieterMenge= new List<Mieter>(){
                                new Mieter(){
                                    Name="DemoName",
                                    MietzinsMenge= new List<Mietzins>(){
                                        new Mietzins(){
                                            StartDate=System.DateTime.Now,
                                            EndDate=System.DateTime.Now},
                                        new Mietzins(){
                                            StartDate=System.DateTime.Now,
                                            EndDate=System.DateTime.Now}
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
         LL.Add(L);
        }
```

## Try to save to DB

```
foreach (Liegenschaft Lieg in LL)
{
    using (var db = new ImmoReportsEntities())
    {
        db.Liegenschaft.Add(Lieg);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }  
 }
```

## Problem

All of my Demo Data can be saved to Database and all FK's are automatically correct created when the MietzinsMenge are NOT Filled!

If i have Data in This MietzinsMenge gives an error: FK_Mietzins_Objekt has identical Primary Key!

### Info

I don't use Forms to insert Data to this Tabel's all Data come from another (external) DB and i want to import this to my DB. How can i import this MietZins too in my Data Tree and have all of this FK (LiegenschftId, ObjektId, MieterId).

Comment: I think you can do without the association Mietzins-Objekt, because you can always find the object via Mieter.

Comment: Thank you GertArnold for your Answer... German Table Names are not good for understand the logic... Mietzins has same role of "Booking entry" witch Mieter has witch Objekt booked (startDate, EndDate) Liegenschaft FK is not really required. it has only be added to insert my Data in logic Tree Format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like you are setting primary key values for your Mietzins objects. You need to either set the primary key values before trying to save to the database or tell EF that the primary keys will be generated by the database.

How you specify that the key is generated by the database depends on whether you are using Code First or Database First. In Code First, it's usualy on by default for integer key types, or you can use the DatabaseGeneratedAttribute and set Identity. For Database First, you use the EF Designer and set the StoreGenerated facet of the key property to Identity.

I re-created your model as shown in the diagram using the following classes and Code First mappings. (I recognize that you are probably not using Code First, but this was the easiest way for me to create the same model with all the relationships as shown in the diagram.)

```
public class Mietzins
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int LiegenschaftId { get; set; }
    public int MieterId { get; set; }
    public int ObjektId { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

    public Liegenschaft Liegenschaft { get; set; }
    public Mieter Mieter { get; set; }
    public Objekt Objekt { get; set; }
}

public class Mieter
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int LiegenschaftId { get; set; }
    public int ObjektId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Liegenschaft Liegenschaft { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Mietzins> MietzinsMenge { get; set; }
    public Objekt Objekt { get; set; }
}

public class Objekt
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int LiegenschaftId { get; set; }
    public int HausId { get; set; }
    public int Zimmer { get; set; }

    public Haus Haus { get; set; }
    public Liegenschaft Liegenschaft { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Mietzins> MietzinsMenge { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Mieter> MieterMenge { get; set; }
}

public class Liegenschaft
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Strasse { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Haus> HausMenge { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Mieter> MieterMenge { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Mietzins> MietzinsMenge { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Objekt> ObjektMenge { get; set; }
}

public class Haus
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int LiegenschaftId { get; set; }
    public int Nummer { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Objekt> ObjektMenge { get; set; }
    public Liegenschaft Liegenschaft { get; set; }
}
```

Context:

```
public class ImmoReportsEntities : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Liegenschaft> Liegenschaft { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Liegenschaft>()
            .HasMany(e => e.HausMenge)
            .WithRequired(e => e.Liegenschaft)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.LiegenschaftId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Liegenschaft>()
            .HasMany(e => e.MieterMenge)
            .WithRequired(e => e.Liegenschaft)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.LiegenschaftId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Liegenschaft>()
            .HasMany(e => e.MietzinsMenge)
            .WithRequired(e => e.Liegenschaft)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.LiegenschaftId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Liegenschaft>()
            .HasMany(e => e.ObjektMenge)
            .WithRequired(e => e.Liegenschaft)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.LiegenschaftId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Haus>()
            .HasMany(e => e.ObjektMenge)
            .WithRequired(e => e.Haus)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.HausId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Objekt>()
            .HasMany(e => e.MietzinsMenge)
            .WithRequired(e => e.Objekt)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.ObjektId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Objekt>()
            .HasMany(e => e.MieterMenge)
            .WithRequired(e => e.Objekt)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.ObjektId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Mieter>()
            .HasMany(e => e.MietzinsMenge)
            .WithRequired(e => e.Mieter)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.MieterId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}
```

I then ran your code exactly as in the question and it worked fine.

I then changed the primary key of Mietzins so that it is no longer database generated:

```
public class Mietzins
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int LiegenschaftId { get; set; }
    public int MieterId { get; set; }
    public int ObjektId { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

    public Liegenschaft Liegenschaft { get; set; }
    public Mieter Mieter { get; set; }
    public Objekt Objekt { get; set; }
}
```

I ran the code again and got the following exception:

Unhandled Exception: System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException:
An error occurred while updating the entries.
See the inner exception for details.
--->
System.Data.UpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries.
See the inner exception for details.
--->
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Mietzins'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Mietzins'.
The statement has been terminated.

If this is different than the exception you are seeing then please post your code and the full exception message and stack trace and I'll take another look.

Comment: Thank you for your help ajcvickers, Table Mietzins has an Identity Column (Id) and is set to autoincrement int. This Model is Database First created. All of the other Tables has no problem with the FK insert. On Image (Link) i have posted you can see the Relationship  Objekt(1)to(many)Mietzins who makes my trouble... I can fill many Haus to List, many Objekt to List, many Mieter to List.. all rows added to db with correct FK to the parent Table. Only the Mietzins can not be used to fill data...

Comment: Hmm.. I am a Noob and can't understand the way you mean. How can i add/overwrite the relation? In a foreach set "new EntityKey" ? in this way i must know the ID of Parent or not? what you mean with "break the big expression" and how to "set the Objekt navigation property of each Mietzens to point to the Objekt instance"? Sorry my "simple" Questions  have you a Sample for me or a Link for similar solution. Thank you so much for your Time.

Comment: Wow your Help is great..! Thank you so much! I have changed to CodeFirst and test your Sample... it works perfect! Now i have added a second "Objekt" to List<Objekt> to test with more realistic data... this give me an error: **Unable to determine the principal end of the Objekt_MietzinsMenge relationship. Multiple added entities may have the same primary key.** And by adding more Haus to List<Haus> is the same error. Add more Mieter to List<Mieter> is no problem. In realistic scenario Liegenschaft can have 1 or more Haus and Haus can have 1 or more Objekt.

Comment: I must give up... After i have implemented this to my WCF Service and try to send some real Data to the Service i run in problems with my "Treeview like" logic! I can't import in this way. Liegenschaft-->Haus-->Objekt are OK but Mieter and Mietzins must be filled under Liegenschaft. Mieter is no problem only FK to Liegenschaft is needed. After SaveChanges the FK for Mietzins must be set with Helper Query's. (ok it's not optimal) "My problem are i have duplicate Data on Destination DB!" Thank you for the good Help and Code. I can use the most of this! And the best => i learned many!